# type checking and method lookup

Tags: java

I'm confused about the functionality of type checking and method lookup in Java.

From what I understand, type checking is done at the compile time and method lookup is done at the run time.

Type checking is based on the declared type of the reference object whereas method lookup is based on the actual type of the reference.

So suppose the class MyInt is a superclass of the class GaussianInt as follows:

```
class MyInt 
{ 
    private int n; 
    public myInt(int n)
    { 
        this.n = n;
    }
    public int getval()
    {
        return n;
    }
    public void increment(int n)
    { 
        this.n += n;
    }
    public myInt add(myInt N)
    { 
        return new myInt(this.n + N.getval());
    }
    public void show()
    { 
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}

class GaussInt extends MyInt 
{ 
    private int m; //represents the imaginary part
    public GaussInt(int x, int y)
    { 
        super(x); 
        this.m = y;
    }
    public void show()
    { 
        System.out.println( "realpart is: " + this.getval() +" imagpart is: " + m);
    }
    public int realpart() 
    { 
        return getval();
    } 
    public int imagpart() 
    {
        return m;
    }
    public GaussInt add(GaussInt z)
    { 
        return new GaussInt(z.realpart() + realpart(), z.imagpart() + imagpart()); 

}
```

And suppose in the main method we have the following:

```
GaussInt z = new GaussInt(3,4); 
MyInt b = z;
MyInt d = b.add(b)
System.out.println("the value of d is:"+ d.show());
```

Which add method would be used in the show statement inside the print statement in the end?

From what I understand, b is declared to be MyInt, but it is, in fact, GuaussInt. The type checker only sees that b is of MyInt type and that it has add(MyInt) so the code makes sense and compiles.

But then in run time, the method lookup sees that b is of type GaussInt and it has two add() methods, so it will use add(GaussInt) method by looking at method signature and it produces a GaussInt. But d is of type MyInt and method lookup will think it won't work, then will it go back to add(Myint)?

How does the mechanism behind compiling and running of a program work?

Comment: add(gaussInt z) does not override add(myInt), because they don't have the same signature. So add(gaussInt) can't be chosen at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand, b is declared to be MyInt, but it is, in fact,
>   GaussInt

You are **CORRECT**. `b`'s reference type is `MyInt` but it is pointing to an object of `GaussInt` type.

> But then in run time, the method lookup sees that b is of type
>   GaussInt and it has two add() methods, so it will use add(GaussInt)
>   method by looking at method signature and it produces a GaussInt. But
>   d is of type GaussInt and method lookup will think it won't work, then
>   will it go back to add(Myint)?

As the add method in `GaussInt` takes a reference of `GaussInt` type and not of `MyInt` type. So `b.add(b)` will call add method of `MyInt` type. Since the gaussInt has two add methods one take the argument of type `MyInt` and other takes the argument `GaussInt` type. So it will call `add` method of `myInt(superclass)`.

The thing you are trying to achieve is **method overriding**. For it to work the **method signatures should be same**. That is, the parent and child class methods should match in every respect, except that the return type of child class method can be `subtype` of the return type of parent class method

SO in order to achieve what you have mentioned, that is `b.add(b)` should call `add` method of `gaussInt`, **make the argument type of add method in both classes same.**

Also what you should learn about is **dynamic polynorphism**(run time check) and **static polymorphism**(compile time type check).